# HotSwapAgent failed to convert filePath to classPathPath

Tags: java, spring, hotswapagent

i am trying to use the HotSwapAgent in our Project.
We are using a Wildfly 10.x and our Project is deployed as an exploded EAR in which there is an exploded war.
I've added the following JVM-options:

```
-XXaltjvm=dcevm -javaagent:c:\dev\hotswap-agent.jar
```

When my WildFly is deploying i get the following Error:

```
HOTSWAP AGENT: 14:42:40.479 ERROR (org.hotswap.agent.plugin.spring.scanner.XmlBeanDefinationScannerAgent) - failed to convert filePath /C:/dev/projects/project_abc/abc/ABC/target/ABC_Exploded.ear/ABCWeb.war/WEB-INF/config/spring/soap-context.xml to classPath path
```

When i let the Wildfly run, later the following Error is shown and the Deployment fails.

```
rror creating bean with name 'systemConfigurationService' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/config/spring/service-maintenance-context.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException
```

Does anyone know how to configure this right ? 
I've read that you can put an extraClassPath into the properties of the HotswapAgent but i've no clue what i should set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change the **convertToClasspathURL** in **org.hotswap.agent.plugin.spring.scanner.XmlBeanDefinationScannerAgent** in order to your needs.

Seems in your case above just the following to the method:

```
paths = filePath.split("WEB-INF/config/spring");
        if (paths.length == 2) {
            return paths[1];
        }
```

**convertToClasspathURL** ( after modifying it for your classpath needs ) :

```
private static String convertToClasspathURL(String filePath) {
        String[] paths = filePath.split("src/main/resources/");
        if (paths.length == 2) {
            return paths[1];
        }

        paths = filePath.split("WEB-INF/classes/");
        if (paths.length == 2) {
            return paths[1];
        }

        paths = filePath.split("target/classes/");
        if (paths.length == 2) {
            return paths[1];
        }

        paths = filePath.split("target/test-classes/");
        if (paths.length == 2) {
            return paths[1];
        }

paths = filePath.split("WEB-INF/config/spring");
            if (paths.length == 2) {
                return paths[1];
            }

        LOGGER.error("failed to convert filePath {} to classPath path", filePath);
        return filePath;
    }
```

Hope it solves your problem!

Comment: Can you explain with more detail where this property (?) has to be changed?

Comment: @AlbertoR. this isn't a property but you have to download the source code of the HotswapAgent and modify the file **XmlBeanDefinationScannerAgent** file for adding this.

Comment: @antii I'm glad it helped! :)